# Using the 'control' option in Proc Template

Tags: sas

I am not sure when I would benefit from using the control option in Proc Template when I am creating a table.

I understand that it controls which column sets the format of the space between each row but I cannot understand how this would be useful for anything as most of the column's formatting is irrelevant to space between rows.

If we have something like this:

```
proc template;
define table theTable;

column one two;
double_space=on;
overline=on;
underline=on;

define one;
**control=on;**
generic=on;
id=on;
vjust=top;
style=data;
end;

define two;
generic=on;
header="Total Dollars Raised";
vjust=top;
end;
run;
```

Most of the options would not be relevant to between row space.  I get the feeling I have misunderstood some aspect of this or that my information is not complete. What would you be expecting to be able to control with the control option?

Comment: You're going to need to clarify your question some.  Can you at least clarify what variety of PROC TEMPLATE you're using - are you using it to build a table, build a crosstab, a style, or something else?  Questions like this are better with an example code so they're not entirely open ended.